# Having worry with code! I'm using C# and SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to write a client query (full name, age, telephone, image, etc) using the combobox (choosing a name) and automatically want the data to be displayed in the textbox. It works ok except the image and throws an error:

> There is no row at position 0

My code:

```
//combobox load
private void cbmodificar_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MELVIN-PC\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog= World_Computers; Integrated Security=True;");

    string query = "select * from agregar_cliente where Nombre='" + cbmodificar.Text + "'";
    SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

    conn.Open();

    SqlDataReader leer = comando.ExecuteReader();

    if (leer.Read() == true)
    {
        idclienteTextBox.Text = leer["idcliente"].ToString();
        txtnombre.Text = leer["Nombre"].ToString();
        txtapellido.Text = leer["Apellido"].ToString();
        txtcedula.Text = leer["Cedula"].ToString();
        txtedad.Text = leer["Edad"].ToString();
        txttelefono.Text = leer["Teléfono"].ToString();
        txtdireccion.Text = leer["Dirreción"].ToString();
        txtcorreo.Text = leer["Correo"].ToString();
        cbestado.Text = leer["Estado"].ToString();
        cbsexo.Text = leer["Sexo"].ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        idclienteTextBox.Text="";
        txtnombre.Text=""; 
        txtapellido.Text="";  
        txtcedula.Text="";  
        txtedad.Text="";  
        txttelefono.Text="";  
        txtdireccion.Text=""; 
        txtcorreo.Text=""; 
        cbestado.Text="";
        cbsexo.Text = ""; 
    }

    leer.Close();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet("agregar_cliente");
    SqlDataAdapter dp = new SqlDataAdapter(query,conn);
    byte[] misdatos = new byte[0];

    dp.Fill(ds, "agregar_cliente");

    DataRow myrow = ds.Tables["agregar_cliente"].Rows[0];  //<<< i dont know//
    misdatos = (byte[])myrow["Imagen"];

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(misdatos);

    imagenPictureBox.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
}
```

Comment: try this :if (leer .HasRows)   
{   
    while (leer.Read())   
        {   
            idclienteTextBox.Text = leer["idcliente"].ToString();
            txtnombre.Text = leer["Nombre"].ToString();
            txtapellido.Text = leer["Apellido"].ToString();
            txtcedula.Text = leer["Cedula"].ToString();


        }   
  

dr.Close();   
}

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if there is a row that you want to access,

```
if (ds.Tables["agregar_cliente"].Rows.Count > 0)
{
DataRow myrow = ds.Tables["agregar_cliente"].Rows[0]; 

......
}
```

Comment: sorry but im new here and not speak so much English !!!!